# Удаление повторов из очереди LinkedList

Tags: java

Есть следующий код:

```
short[][] test = new short[6][2];
Queue<short[]> arr = new LinkedList<short[]>();
```

Массив `test` заполнен следующим образом:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Есть функция добавления элемента в `LinkedList`:

```
private static void AddElement(short[] in, Queue<short[]> link_arr, int max_size)
{
    // удалить самый старый элемент если очередь больше max_size
    if (link_arr.size() > max_size)
    {
       link_arr.poll();
    }
    link_arr.add(in);
    Set<short[]> set_arr = new LinkedHashSet<short[]>(link_arr);
    link_arr.clear();
    link_arr.addAll(set_arr);
}
```

Вызывается следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
{
    AddElement(test[i], arr, max_size);
}
```

В итоге после выполнения программы в `arr` всё равно лежат повторяющиеся элементы. Если `arr` является просто списком из `short`, то всё работает.

Можно ли средствами Java библиотек получить уникальный список, или придется всё писать самому?

Comment: `HashMap` смотрели? Или `HashSet`

Comment: Если речь идет о HashMap или HashSet вместо LinkedList, то нет, мне нужен функционал именно очереди. Если вместо LinkedHashSet, то пробовал, то же самое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать массив в качестве ключа в `Map` плохая затея, потому что нельзя рассчитывать на то, что два массива, содержащие одинаковые элементы, будут иметь одинаковый hash code и возвращать `true` при сравнении с помощью `equals`.

Одним из вариантов решения проблемы является создание для массива класса-обёртки, реализующего методы `hashCode` и `equals`:

```
private static class Element
{
    public final short[] values;

    public Element(short[] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj instanceof Element)
        {
            return Arrays.equals(values, ((Element)obj).values);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Arrays.hashCode(values);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    short[][] test = { { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }, { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }, { 1,2 }, { 3,4 } };
    Set<Element> uniqueElements = new HashSet<>();
    for (short[] group : test)
    {
        uniqueElements.add(new Element(group));
    }
    List<short[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element element : uniqueElements)
    {
        result.add(element.values);
    }
}
```

Вместо `HashSet` можно использовать `LinkedHashSet`, равно как и `LinkedList` вместо `ArrayList`, - для получения уникальных элементов это не принципиально.

В Java 8 метод `main` может выглядеть так:

```
short[][] test = { { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }, { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }, { 1,2 }, { 3,4 } };
List<short[]> result = Stream.of(test)
        .map(Element::new)
        .distinct()
        .map(e -> e.values)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Если обязательно нужно добавлять элементы в очередь по одному в отдельном методе, то можно преобразовать исходный код так:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    short[][] test = { { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }, { 1,2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5,6 }, { 3,4 } };
    Queue<Element> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    for (short[] group : test)
    {
        addElement(group, queue, 10);
    }
}

private static void addElement(short[] array, Queue<Element> queue, int maxSize)
{
    Element element = new Element(array);
    if (queue.contains(element))
    {
        return;
    }
    while (queue.size() >= maxSize)
    {
        queue.poll();
    }
    queue.add(element);
}
```

Есть вместо блокировки добавления дубля нужно добавлять элемент заново в конец очереди, то вместо

```
if (queue.contains(element)) { return; }
```

достаточно использовать

```
queue.remove(element);
```

Comment: @user239737 что именно непонятно? Метод `Arrays.equals` сравнивает поэлементно два массива. Если они различаются, то метод возвращает `true`.

Comment: Все, ок, немного затупил, пока писал понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Так как добавляются разные объекты массивов, без переопределенного `equals()`, то set сравнивает хеш-коды (ссылки) обращаясь к родителю `Object`, а они отличаются у разных объектов. Если хочешь удалять семантически разные значения на уровне логики приложения, то условие сравнения объектов должен прописать сам (переопределить `equals()`)

Comment: Как я понимаю мне надо переопределить equals() и hashCode() и  после этого в LinkedHashSet будут только уникальные значения?

Comment: Да. Кстати, судя по коду, выбор `LinkedHashSet` не обусловлен, он обеспечивает порядок вывода компонентов в порядке добавления, что ненужно.

Comment: LinkedHashSet в данной примере может и не совсем обусловлен, но мне критичен порядок добавления, т.к. нужна именно очередь.

Comment: Еще вопрос если можно? У меня добавление элементов в очередь реализовано статическим методом в классе (я создал сервисный класс с набором статических методов, чтобы его использовать по всему проекту). Если я переопределяю equals() для того чтобы корректно работал AddElement, однако в дальнейшем мне понадобится другой equals(), то как можно обойти эту ситуацию?

Comment: Если честно, то я считаю объявление статических методов и переменных крахом ООП дизайна (это я от чтения Фаулера заразился). Лучший вариант определять поведение объекта в самом объекте. <br/> Если же рассматривать именно такую компоновку, которая есть, то статический класс лучше переписать принимающим компаратор, как переменную логику и проводить сравнения в одном классе, но с разными компараторами.